# Edit clear button method in ngx daterange picker

Tags: angular, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am trying to set minDate and maxDate of my calendar dinamically. I used several methods to do that, however, **I want to reset those values to null with the "Clear" button**.

In my .ts I have this:

```
startDateClicked($event) {
    this.maxDate = moment($event.startDate._d).add(7, 'days');
  }
  endDateClicked($event) {
    this.minDate = moment($event.endDate._d).subtract(7, 'days');
  }
```

And in my html, I have this:

```
<input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd formControlName="pick_dates"
                class="form-control" placeholder="Select" [ranges]="ranges" [alwaysShowCalendars]="true"
                [showClearButton]="true" [keepCalendarOpeningWithRange]="true"
                opens="center"
                [showRangeLabelOnInput]="true"  
                [maxDate]='maxDate' (startDateChanged)="startDateClicked($event)"
                (endDateChanged)="endDateClicked($event)" [timePicker]="true" [locale] = "locale"/>
```

In the Clear button method I want to set this:

```
this.maxDate=null
this.minDate=null
```

Comment: I found the parameter!!! In html just add [dateLimit]=7, in my case, it works in "days"

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some default date in max and min date.

```js
this.minDate=moment(new Date()).subtract(1, 'month');
 this.maxDate = moment(new Date()).add(1, 'month');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the parameter!!! In html just add

```
[dateLimit]=7
```

, in my case, it works in "days"